# Problem editing word file in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office

So I need to edit some text in a Word document. I created a Word document and saved it as XML. It is saved correctly (I can open the XML file in MS Word and it looks exactly like the docx original).

So then I use PHP DOM to edit some text in the file (just two lines) (EDIT - bellow is already fixed working version):

```
<?php

$firstName = 'Richard';
$lastName = 'Knop';

$xml = file_get_contents('template.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$wts = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main', 't');

$c1 = 0; $c2 = 0;
foreach ($wts as $wt) {

    if (1 === $c1) {
        $wt->nodeValue .= ' ' . $firstName;
        $c1++;
    }

    if (1 === $c2) {
        $wt->nodeValue .= ' ' . $lastName;
        $c2++;
    }

    if ('First Name' === substr($wt->nodeValue, 0, 10)) {
        $c1++;
    }

    if ('Last Name' === substr($wt->nodeValue, 0, 9)) {
        $c2++;
    }

}

$xml = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $xml); 

$fp = fopen('final-xml.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);
```

This gets executed properly (no errors). These two lines:

```
<w:t>First Name:</w:t>
<w:t>Last Name:</w:t>
```

Get replaced with these:

```
<w:t>First Name: Richard</w:t>
<w:t>Last Name: Knop</w:t>
```

However, when I try to open the final-xml.xml file in MS Word, it doesn't open (Word freezes). Any suggestions.

EDIT:

I tried using levenstein():

```
$xml = file_get_contents('template.xml');
$xml2 = file_get_contents('final-xml.xml');

$str = str_split($xml, 255);
$str2 = str_split($xml2, 255);

$i = 0;
foreach ($str as $s) {
    $dist = levenshtein($s, $str2[$i]);
    if (0 <> $dist) {
        echo $dist, '<br />';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Which outputted nothing.

Which is weird. When I open the final-xml.xml file in notepad, I can clearly see that those two lines have changed.

EDIT2:

Here is the template.xml file: http://uploading.com/files/61b2922b/template.xml/

Comment: could this be a character encoding problem?

Comment: could you `diff` the original and the result, to verify that this is in fact the only change you made?

Comment: I'm going to use array_diff to try and differentiate both XML files.

Comment: @Matt Ellen It shouldn't be. Both XML files have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> in the beginning and my PHP script is UTF-8 as well.

Comment: @Richard thx. I don't think str_split (which splits per character) will work - you only proved that there is no character in file1 which is not there in file2. Use command line `diff`, possibly with `-b` to ignore white space changes or `-w` to ignore white space alltoghether.

Comment: @mvds I'm on Windows machine so I cannot use cmd very effectively (I tried diff command and it does not know it). But I have used the levenstein distance algorithm. Gonna update my wuestion right now.

Comment: If you need to run a diff on a windows machine, I would recommend WinMerge - http://winmerge.org/

Comment: @richard as a quick fix, do the array diff as you did it, but `explode("\n")` the files in separate lines instead. (would ms word choke on `\r\n` vs `\n` line endings?)

Comment: OK. I'm installing WinMerge. Meanwhile, I double checked encodings. Both files are UTF-8.

Comment: You code works as expected. The problem might be with the input document. Are you sure that the searched text is only found in two places?

Comment: @0xA3 I am using Word XML format (not 2003, it's the newer one that's used by default in MS Office 2007).

Comment: @0xA3 Yes the searched text appears only once in the document.

Comment: @0xA3 I have added the template.xml file. Check my updated question.

Comment: @0xA3: Yes it works but when I try to open final-xml.xml in MS Office it freezes and does not open (I have to do Ctrl + Alt + Del and close MS Word).

Comment: @0xA3 Have you tried opening the final-xml.xml in Word? Did it work?

Comment: Meh. When I try to open it, Word freezes and I have to go Ctrl + Alt + Del.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce this with Word 2007 now. It is working in Word 2010 which I have been using before to test this.

Comment: I tried it in Word 2007 in safe mode. It still freezes.

Comment: Maybe I will just create a pdf file and add texts there with Zend_Pdf. This seems like it cannot be solved so using Word is not an option.

Comment: @0xA3 Yes I'm using Word 2007, not 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem related to DOS vs UNIX line endings. Word 2007 does not tolerate a `\n` line ending, it requires `\r\n` whereas Word 2010 is more tolerant and accepts both versions.

To fix the problem make sure that you replace all UNIX line breaks with DOS ones before saving the output file:

```
$xml = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $xml);
```

Full sample:

```
<?php

$firstName = 'Richard';
$lastName = 'Knop';

$xml = file_get_contents('template.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$wts = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main', 't');

foreach ($wts as $wt) {
   echo $wt->nodeValue;

    if ('First Name:' === $wt->nodeValue) {
        $wt->nodeValue = 'First Name: ' . $firstName;
    }

    if ('Last Name:' === substr($wt->nodeValue, 0, 10)) {
        $wt->nodeValue = 'Last Name: ' . $lastName;
    }
}

$xml = $doc->saveXML();

// Replace UNIX with DOS line endings
$xml = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $xml); 

$fp = fopen('final-xml.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML Word files have certain checksums stored near the top of the dom (to my recollection).  You may have to change these, such as the size, or general checksum itself.

I know this was my problem when I was (dumb) enough to make an HTML file in word and save it, it has thousands of useless things in it that only served to make editing worse.

Comment: These are no checksums, they are just meta data which will be updated by Word once the document is saved again.